# redirect to different view after loading partial view in Main view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, http-redirect, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I dint find answers to this and tried several ways. any help would be appreciated thanks !!
I have view which updates the page without reloading on each click using ajax scripts. Below is the code. but after entire partial views are generated, I want user to redirect complete different view on clicking a link which is not associated to controller user is in now.

**my View**

```
    @model IMONLP.Models.Search
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Search";
    }
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>


        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "results" 
}))
        {
            <br />        
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.search_text, new { style = "width: 200px;" })
            <input type="submit" value="search" />
        }

           @Ajax.ActionLink("Try Demo", "PLNHK", "PLNHK", new AjaxOptions { })
       // this ajax link should redirect to different view,

    <div id="results">
        @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(@Model.search_text))
        {
            Html.RenderPartial("Searchprocess", Model);
        }
    </div>
```

**My controller:**

```
public ActionResult Search(Search s)
        {
            //do something

            return PartialView("Searchprocess", s);    
        }

public ActionResult Selected(Search s)
        {
            //DO something
            return PartialView("Selected", s);
        }
```

The above "TryDEMO" "PLNHK" ajax action link will have to be redirected to new controller and new action and return view thats returned by that action. everytime I click on that, I found it moving to that controller  and then to corresponding view but again its getting back to old page. I used @html.actionlink instead of Ajax, but now I get this error

```
The "RenderBody" method has not been called for layout page "~/Views/PLNHK/PLNHK.cshtml".

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
```

**EDIT** : I did create PLNHK.cshtml. while I'm trying to debug this, the control goes to PLNHK controller then to PLNHK view(PLNHK.cshtml) parses each and every step in that page, but finally I would get the output to be the older page. I was thinking may be the Ajax scripts on before page is the reason.

Comment: with Html.Actionlink, it should work, are you sure you have created the PLNHK view?

Comment: YEs. I did create that. Please check my EDIT.Thanks !

Comment: I don't know if this is the solution but the script tags are in the wrong place, they should be in a script section at the bottom of the page

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this? I din't understand !!

Comment: I found the answer : It has to  be Html.Actionlink instead of Ajax. Nothing to do with scripts and in PLNHk controlller it has to return a view . I used return View(PLNHK, PLNHK), it just has to be return View(); if you are  already in default page.

Comment: @RJ24 Can you add your last comment as an answer so that other users can benefit from that as well?